# How do hide an element that is a children of tabl'es cell <td>?

Tags: jquery

I have an array of strings:

```
var matchThese = ["Jabberwocky", "Harry Potter", "Some other"];
```

And I have this HTML:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <table>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <a title="Harry Potter" href="http://harryPotter.net">
                <img title="Harry Potter"></img>
               </a>
             </td>
             <td>
               <a title="HideThisOne" href="">
                 <img title="HideThisOne"></img>
               </a>
             </td>
             <td> 
               <a title="HideThisOneToo" href="">
                <img/>
               </a>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>
              <a title="Jabberwocky" href=""> <img></img></a>
             </td>
             <td>
               <a title="123" href=""> <img></img></a>
             </td>
               ...

            </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
```

I want to be able to itterate through all of the `<table>` tags and their `<a>` elements, match their titles by what is specified in the array and hide all the other `<td>` of that same table if they do not match. But only hide those `<td>` of the table where there is at least one match for the title of an `<a>` element from the hardcoded array.

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest starting by reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from something like this

```
    $('table td').each(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < matchThese.length; i++){
        if($(this).find('a').attr('title')!=matchThese[i])
            $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UmHeQ/)**?

jQuery:

```
var matchThese = ["Jabberwocky", "Harry Potter", "Some other"];
$('td a').hide();
$('td').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($('a', this).attr('title'), matchThese) >= 0) {
        $('a', this).show();
    }
});​
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a title="Harry Potter" href="http://harryPotter.net">a</a></td>
        <td><a title="HideThisOne" href="">a</a></td>
        <td><a title="HideThisOneToo" href="">a</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a title="Jabberwocky" href="">a</a></td>
        <td><a title="123" href="">a</a></td>
        <td><a title="123" href="">a</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​